# Proof of the basic counting rule (BCR) by induction

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

I am going through my notes studying for my intro probability course test. I am trying to prove as many theorems as I can from the course notes as this is something we may be tested on, as well I find it satisfying to be able to prove a theorem that you use so commonly in application on your own.

I want to prove the basic counting rule using induction. The rule goes as follows:

If $r$ experiments are to be preformed in such a way that there are $m_{1}$ outcomes to the first experiment, for each outcome of experiment 1 there are $m_{2}$ outcomes to the second experiment, and so on, resulting in:

$m_{1} \cdot m_{2} \cdot m_{3} \ldots \cdot m_{r}$ = $\prod_{i = 1}^{r} m_{i}$

I have tried to do the proof on my own but I think that my base case is missing something and my inductive step is incomplete. Here I what I have so far:

Base Case:

Suppose only two events occur, let event 1 be $m_{1}$, and for each of those $m_{1}$ events $m_{2}$ events occur. We have the following:

$m_{1} \cdot m_{2} = \prod_{i = 1}^{2} m_{i}$ = number of outcomes

(Here is where I think my base case is incomplete, this shows the formula holds but I feel as if I am missing something here).

Inductive Steps:

Suppose that $p(N) = m_{N}$ for N that is an element of the positive integers. Assume that $p(N)$ is true. We want to prove that $p(N+1)$ is also true.

$\prod_{i = 1}^{N+1} m_{i} = m_{1} \cdot m_{2} \cdot m_{3} \ldots \cdot m_{N} \cdot m_{N+1}$

$\prod_{i = 1}^{N+1} m_{i} = \prod_{i = 1}^{N} m_{i} \cdot m_{N+1}$

Since we assumed that $p(N)$ is true and $p(N+1)$ is just the products of $p(N)$ and $p(N+1)$ we conclude that $p(N+1)$ must also be true.

I think I am missing some things here and my proof is incomplete. Any help is greatly appreciated and I'm open to discussing. I want to be able to understand how to apply induction to many different situations.